# Kohana. Environment Tests. Filters not Enabled

Tags: php, filter, kohana

I use Kohana for my project, but when i located my project to hosting, environment test watch write it: The filter extension is either not loaded or not compiled in.
I don`t understand... what is the problem?

Sorry, for my language.

Comment: What Kohana version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

We use the filter extensions for some areas of the framework.

Comment: where I can turn on it in PHP?

Comment: You need to speak to your hosting provider to compile the filter extension in.